# Incremental Backup in tortoisesvn

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have to execute incremental backup for my SVN repositry on daily basis. I don't want to automate it, manual command/script execution will work for me. 
Could anybody tell me the command/script to be used for incremental backup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Backing up should not be done via TortoiseSVN; this should instead be done with direct access to the repository. See http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.backup

Answer (score 0):

You could generate a sequence of patch files http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-patch.html

Answer (score 0):

From FileSystem point of view Subversion repository is just usual directory. You can use any backup-tool on server side